# Core Data NSFetchRequest for Specific Relationship?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, entity-relationship

I'm transitioning an existing data model that was previously stored in XML to Core Data, so I'm trying to learn the ropes as properly as possible. Core Data is obviously one of those technologies that isn't going anywhere anytime soon, so I might as well "learn it right."

Take for example a Core Data model with two Entities:

1. **Person**
2. **Food**

**Person** has 2 one-to-many relationships with **Food**:

1. favoriteFoods (1-to-many)
2. hatedFoods (1-to-many)

*(Both Person and Food are subclasses of NSManagedObject as well.)*

In the previous data model, **Person** maintained two `NSArray` instance variables. If I wanted favorite foods, I could call:

```
Person *fred = [[Person alloc] init];    
NSArray *fredsFavorites = fred.favoriteFoods;
```

Easy squeezy.

I'm reading through the documentation for Core Data, and I can't seem to find the right way to obtain this NSArray given an `NSFetchRequest`, because *I can't define which relationship I want to obtain objects from.*

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:[fred managedObjectContext]]];
[request setIncludesSubentities:NO];
NSArray *fredsFavoriteAndHatedFoods = [[fred managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

This returns all of the **Food** items stored in both `favoriteFoods` and `hatedFoods`. How can I split these up? Surely there's a simple explanation, but I don't currently grasp the concept well enough to explain it in Core Data jargon, thus my Google searches are fruitless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most straightforward way to get it is to simply access the relationship `NSSet` directly:

```
NSArray *fredsFavorites = [fred.favoriteFoods allObjects];
```

(I've shown how to get an `NSArray` from the resulting `NSSet`).

Alternatively, if you haven inverse relationship set up (which you should) you could use a fetch request like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:[fred managedObjectContext]]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY personsWithThisAsFavorite == %@", fred]];
NSArray *fredsFavoriteFoods = [[fred managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

This assumes that `personsWithThisAsFavorite` is the inverse relationship to `favoriteFoods`. Unless I'm reading your example wrong, `favoriteFoods` should really be a many-to-many relationship, since a person can have multiple favorite foods, and a food can have multiple people with that food as a favorite.

(Note that I haven't tested this, so the `NSPredicate` might not be 100% correct)

Comment: Perfect - the [fred.favoriteFoods allObjects] bit is exactly what I was looking for. Follow-up question though - is there a way to sort the NSArray in that call, eg. [fred.favoriteFoods allObjectsUsingSortDescriptor:myDescriptor]? Or is it required that I call the sort method on the returned NSArray? (Just seems like it would require less memory to sort it during the first method call.)

Comment: Yes, you can use `allObjectsUsingSortDescriptor:`. Depending on your exact circumstances, it may be faster to do the sorting either in the fetch request itself, or doing it in RAM once you've loaded the objects (with `allObjectsUsingSortDescriptor:` or something similar). It really depends on your exact data model and how much data you're working with. When I say "on the fetch request itself", I'm referring to the `NSFetchRequest.sortDescriptors` property.

Comment: Oh - didn't even see that sortDescriptors property on the NSFetchRequest. Nice.